# Showing that a lower triangular matrix is positive definite

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-definite

How can I show that the following square matrix is positive definite?

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
 1 &  0 &  0 &  0 & \dots &  0 & 0\\
-1 &  1 &  0 &  0 & \dots &  0 & 0\\
 0 & -1 &  1 &  0 & \dots &  0 & 0\\
 0 &  0 & -1 &  1 & \dots &  0 & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots\\
 0 &  0 &  0 &  0 & \dots & -1 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

I can manually show the $1 \times 1$, $2 \times 2$, $3 \times 3$ squares have eigenvalue equal to $1$, but how do I generalize that?

Comment: Positive definite and **non**-symmetric are a dangerous mix.

Comment: What do you mean by "positive definite"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matrix A has a positive definite because it's lower triangular matrix and
the definite of upper(lower) triangular matrix is equal to the product of its diagonal elements.

Comment: what is this theorem called?

Comment: Well, it is not a theorem as well, but it’s a property of diagonal matrix

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

The determinant of all the principal minors is positive (in fact, it is $\;1\;$ in all cases).

Answer (score 0):

In this case it's easier to use Sylvester's criterion.

All the principal minors are easy to evaluate and they are all $1 > 0 \implies$ the matrix is positive definite.